# I have a new android phone and want to migrate all my applications from my old phone using adb

Tags: android, copy, adb

I don't want to use Google (privacy reasons) or many of the applications that are already available to do this. I want to use ADB.

I want to do this from my linux laptop.

Comment: It seems like this question might be better suited for android.stackexchange.com? I'm not sure it falls within the scope of stackoverflow. 
Also, your question might be improved by adding some information about what you have tried already, and what problems you have faced thus far.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

1. install adb
2. connect old phone
3. run "adb root"
4. run "adb pull /data/app/"
5. connect new phone
6. run "adb root"
7. run "for d in app/*/; do (cd "$d" &&  adb install base.apk); done"

hope this helps someone with the issue I faced.